# No matching signature for operator < for argument types: STRING, INT64

Tags: google-bigquery

SELECT
CAST(CONCAT(TRIM(SUBSTR(Date, 6,5)),"-",IF(SUBSTR(Date, 1,1)<10,0,""),SUBSTR(Date, 1,1),"-",SUBSTR(Date, 3,2))AS DATE)
FROM `XXXXX` LIMIT 1000

hello, Guys I have problems with "IF" because I want to put a condition for the month. Someone can help me, please?

thank you for your time

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)